# MATLAB Make Matrices same size

Tags: matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, I have five single matrices representing joint skeletal data I have collected from a Kinect sensor. Each matrice is roughly 240-270 x 3 in size (each contains x,y,z data for that joint). I am trying to combine all these joints into one matrix, so I can filter the results.

X = [J1 J2 J3 J4 J5]

The trouble is each matrix is not the same size so at the moment I get an error trying to combine the data.

I want to be able to combine these matrices but make them the same size. I cannot remove the first few lines as they are time synced, and so the first coordinate of each joint was captured at the same time. I would like to, however, calculate the size of the smallest matrix and reshape the others to that size, by removing the last rows in the matrices so that I don't lose important data.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Zero pad, or use cells/structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible.  Do exactly as you said.  Find the matrix that has the smallest amount of rows and make sure that you extract up to this row index for each of the other matrices, then piece them all together:

You have 5 separate matrices and so finding the row size of each then finding the minimum is a lot of code.  I would place all of the matrices in a cell array, then make a call to [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to find the size of each row in one go, then do what I said above:

```
%// Build cell array of all matrices
J = {J1, J2, J3, J4, J5};

%// Find rows of all matrices
rows = cellfun(@(x) size(x,1), J);

%// Find the smallest amount of rows
min_row = min(rows);

%// Create a new matrix that ensures that we only sample up to that many
%// rows for each matrix
X = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(1:min_row,:), J, 'uni', 0);
```

The last `cellfun` call is different from the first one because what is being output is a set of **matrices** instead of a set of singular values.  Therefore, you have to set the `'uni=0'` flag to let MATLAB know that the output won't be singular values anymore.  Instead, each truncated matrix will be in its own cell and so to piece all of the cells together, you need to use [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) to finish things off.

Comment: No problem. If you no longer need help, please consider accepting my answer. That can be done by clicking the checkmark at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down voting buttons. Good luck!